# Call async method in an inner lambda? "This construct may only be used within computation expressions"

Tags: f#

I have the following code

```
let rec consume() : Async<unit> = async {
    .....
    listA 
    |> Seq.iter(fun i ->
        .....
        let listB : seq<...> option = 
            let c = getListB a b
            match c with 
            | Some d -> Seq.filter(....) |> Some
            | None -> None 
        match listB with .....
    ....
```

Now the function `getListB` is converted to return `async<Seq<B>>` instead of `Seq<B>`. So the code was converted to the following. However, the `getListB` blocked the execution. How to rewrite it nonblocking? Simply convert the line to `let! c = getListB a b` won't work because the code is in an inner lambda? The error message is "This construct may only be used within computation expressions".

```
let rec consume() : Async<unit> = async {
    .....
    listA 
    |> Seq.iter(fun i ->
        .....
        let listB : seq<...> option = 
            let c = getListB a b |> Async.RunSynchronously
            match c with 
            | Some d -> Seq.filter(....) |> Some
            | None -> None
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you want to run each element of the sequence sequentially or in parallel.

In both cases, start by using `Seq.map` instead of `Seq.iter`, then you can put another `async` block inside the lambda such that the result of the `map` is `seq<Async<'a>>`.

**Sequential**

For this, you need define some extra functions in an extra `Async` module.

```
module Async = 
    let map f x =
        async{
            let! x = x
            return f x
        }

    let lift2 f x1 x2 = 
        async{
            let! x1 = x1
            let! x2 = x2
            return f x1 x2
        }

    let return' x = async { return x }

    let mapM mFunc sequ =
        let consF x ys = lift2 (fun h t -> h::t) (mFunc x) ys
        Seq.foldBack(consF) sequ (return' [])
        |> map (Seq.ofList)

    let sequence sequ = mapM id sequ
```

You might have seen `mapM` called `traverse` elsewhere, they are basically just different names for the same concept.

The `sequence` function is just a special case of `mapM` where the supplied binding function is just the identity (`id`) function.  It has type `seq<Async<'a>> -> Async<seq<'a>>`, i.e. it flips the `Async` from being inside the `Seq` to being outside.

You then simply pipe the result of your `Seq.map` to the `sequence` function, which gives you an `async` value.

Your example code isn't complete so I made up some example code to use this:

```
let sleep = Async.Sleep 100
let sleeps = Seq.init 15 (fun _ -> sleep)
let sequencedSleeps = Async.sequence sleeps
Async.RunSynchronously sequencedSleeps
```

> ```
> Real: 00:00:01.632, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : seq<unit> =
>   [null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null;
>    null; null; null]
> ```

---

**Parallel**

To execute each element of the sequence in parallel, instead of sequentially, you could do:

```
let pSequence sequ = Async.Parallel sequ |> Async.map (Seq.ofArray)
```

Example test code:

```
let pSleeps = pSequence sleeps;;
Async.RunSynchronously pSleeps;;
```

> ```
> Real: 00:00:00.104, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : seq<unit> = seq [null; null; null; null; ...]
> ```

Note how the execution time depends on the chosen approach.

---

For the cases where you're getting back a `seq<unit>` and so want to ignore the result it can be useful to define some extra helper functions, such as:

```
let sequenceIgnore sequ = sequ |> Async.sequence |> Async.map (ignore)

let pSequenceIgnore sequ = sequ |> pSequence |> Async.map (ignore)
```

That lets you return a single `unit` rather than a superfluous sequence of them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you are describing boils down to how to convert an `seq<Async>` to an `Async<seq>`.  This is described comprehensively in [this post](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/) by Scott Wlaschin.

This is a poor man's implementation of the concepts described in his post which are far more powerful and generic.  The general idea is that we want to delay the creation of the sequence until we have the values promised by the instance of `Async<_>`

```
let traverseSequence ( seqAsync : seq<Async<'a>>) = 

    let promiseOfAnEmptySequence = async  { return Seq.empty }

    let delayedCalculation (asyncHead : Async<'a>) (asyncTail : Async<seq<'a>>) = 
        async {
        let! calculatedHead = asyncHead
        return!
            async {
                let! calculatedTail = asyncTail
                return calculatedHead |> Seq.singleton |> Seq.append(calculatedTail)
            }
        }

    Seq.foldBack delayedCalculation seqAsync promiseOfAnEmptySequence
```